# ajax fail to POST on API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

i tried everything, and i still cant figure out whats the problem, i'm trying to 'POST' something on teachers server that we had for homework, and i have no idea what i'm doing wrong ,i'm stuck for like 2 hours already.

here is my code.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://3uc5taw99i.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/attendees';
let attendee = JSON.stringify({firstName: 'Nikola',lastName:'Nikola',email:'Nikola',dateBirth:'13.12.1869'});
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
    console.log(xhr.response);
  }
}
xhr.open('POST',url);
xhr.send(attendee);
```

Comment: Have you tried logging [`xhr.responseText`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp) instead of `response`?

Comment: i neeed to POST, getting information back is easy, but post is bugging.

Comment: Are you sure you're even making the connection? The log statement would tell you that much.

Comment: yes, im sure, you can test it your self easy, just paste the code in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this snippet, you are getting `The 401 Unauthorized error`, you have to attach authorization token variable to the request.
`xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '~Token~');`

There will be an other api that will get authorization token.

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://3uc5taw99i.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/attendees';
let attendee = JSON.stringify({firstName: 'Nikola',lastName:'Nikola',email:'Nikola',dateBirth:'13.12.1869'});
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
    console.log(xhr.response);
  }
  else{
    console.log(xhr.status); 
  }
}
xhr.open('POST',url);
xhr.send(attendee);
```

Comment: should be ``` xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); ```
but im still getting 401 ;//